# HCSP to JSON through JAVA

Tags: java, json, stellent

I ve a HCSP File used by stellent(oracle product) and need of business is to convert a hcsp file to JSON format via java programming. Is there any standard way existing that I might not be aware of? Please give a pointer how to go for such conversion.

Comment: HCSP to JSON? HCSP is a dynamic web page (HTML + Idoc Script code)!!

Comment: @vzamanillo yeah agree it conatins idoc script code. As of now forget about Idioc Scripting. Lets talk about only html content.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few core Java classes that could assist in this. Some of these are used when IsJson=1 is added in the URL.

Do you need a specific JSON layout? What does your HTML look like?